# Convert float to int error

Tags: float

I am trying to convert 1.06 to 106 by multiplying by 100 but the answer comes 105, I do not know why. Variable ver can be any decimal in this format x.xx

```
float ver = 1.06;
int vers = ver * 100;
vm[0] = (vers / 100U) % 10;
vm[1] = (vers / 10U) % 10;
vm[2] = (vers / 1U) % 10;
Serial.println(vers);
```

Could  you let me know what I am doing wrong or maybe I have to do something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.06 is not a float. The closest float is 1.059999942779541015625. If
you multiply that by 100 you get a number that, again, is not a float.
Rounding to the nearest float yields 105.99999237060546875, which is the
result of the expression `ver * 100`, and just one [ULP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) short of 106.
Yes, floating point computations do quite usually involve rounding
steps.

Casting to an `int` implicitly rounds towards zero, and you get 105,
which is the correct result. Correct according to the rules of IEEE 754
arithmetics.

You may want to `round()` to the nearest integer before the cast.

> Variable ver can be any decimal in this format x.xx

No, a `float` cannot be “any decimal” in this format. Floats are stored
in binary, and most decimal numbers (numbers that can be written with a
finite number of decimal digits) cannot be written in binary with a
finite number of bits.

Except for a few values (namely the multiples of 0.25), `ver` can only
store an *approximation* of the decimal number.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now it make sense.